# Tensorflow: Unable to open table file error

Tags: tensorflow

With tensorflow 1.2.0, I am trying to restore a saved model but I receive the error:

```
DataLossError (see above for traceback): Unable to open table file checkpoints/saved_2/saved_2_model_1.meta: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
 [[Node: save/RestoreV2_185 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_185/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_185/shape_and_slices)]]
```

I am using the same tensorflow version for saving and restoring.

For saving:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
ckpt_dir = os.path.join(params['CHK_PATH'], folder)
if not os.path.exists(ckpt_dir):
    os.makedirs(ckpt_dir)
ckpt_file = os.path.join(ckpt_dir, '{}'.format(name))
path = saver.save(sess, ckpt_file)
```

For restoring:

```
      saver.restore(sess, ckpt_file)
```

I tried: `model_saver = tf.train.Saver(write_version = saver_pb2.SaverDef.V1)`

But the same problem remains.

Comment: Please show the code where you save and restore the model.

Comment: saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(ckpt_dir)) worked

Answer (score 2):

```
    saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(ckpt_dir))
```

works

Comment: instead of the 1liner, if you could explain the reason behind the issue, it would help me in the community to solve the same error. After getting the pre-trained model, my val script is constantly crying out with `DataLossError (see above for traceback): Unable to open table file`, any help would be highly appreciated.